# How to set Yii2 Radiolist ID and onchange method

Tags: php, yii2

I have created radiolist in yii2 like below.How to set onchange method in that.and how to set id for the radiolist

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'design_type')->inline()->radioList(['a' => 'Classic Design', 'b' => 'New Design'])->label(false) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add `options` after `items` in radioList:

change code to:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'design_type')->inline()->radioList(['a' => 'Classic Design', 'b' => 'New Design'],['onChange'=>'handleRadio(this);','id'=>'whatever'])->label(false) ?>
```

Comment: ['a' => 'Classic Design', 'b' => 'New Design','onChange'=>'handleRadio(this);','id'=>'whatever'] this will create  4 radio buttons right??

Comment: @AbhiJith sorry i forgot to seprate them. i edited my answer.

Comment: @ShringirajDewangan so must to use template.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to add any attribute in your input:radio field

```
$form->field($model, 'design_type')->radioList(['a' => 'Classic Design', 'b' => 'New Design'], [
    'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
        $checked = $checked ? 'checked' : '';
        return "<label>
                <input type='radio' {$checked} 
                       name='{$name}' 
                       value='{$value}'
                       id='idName_{$value}'
                       onChange='YourFunctionName();'>
                {$label}</label>";

    }
])
```

[Referance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901986/checked-items-in-yii2-checkboxlist)